# Sumar pixel a un div con window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola estoy tratando de detectar el Height con window.innerHeight con ese valor que obtengo sumar o restar los pixel necesarios, pero al sumar me agrega pixel de mas y al restar me resta la totalidad del Height mas el numero asignado, alguna idea que me indique para saber que estoy haciendo mal?

```
var a = 22;
  var b = 11;
  var valor = window.innerHeight;
     
       resultado = a + valor
  console.log( parseInt(b));
  
 
 
 const ventana = document.getElementById("div");
 ventana.style.height =  parseInt(resultado) + "px";
```

Comment: Necesitamos más información. ¿Estás aplicando estilos a ese div? ¿Tienes paddings, margins, etc.? Poniendo tu código, tal y como está ahí, devuelve que la altura de `ventana` es la suma de `a + window.innerHeight`.

Comment: Creo que sería mejor si publicaras un [mcve], pues aumentaría las probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

Comment: los parseInt no son necesarios ya que declaraste a y b con numeros. por otro lado si no tienes aplicada una position al div no va a crecer mas alla de la altura de la ventana